# PHP cannot find a class

Tags: php, class

Silly question, but I cannot figure out what's wrong. I have a ready to use script that prompts a fatal error when I run it.

```
use DDelivery\Order\DDeliveryOrder;
use DDelivery\Order\DDeliveryProduct;
use DDelivery\Order\DDStatusProvider;

class IntegratorShop extends \DDelivery\Adapter\PluginFilters {
...
```

The error is:

> Fatal error: Class 'DDelivery\Adapter\PluginFilters' not found in
>   .../ddelivery/IntegratorShop.php on
>   line 40

Frankly I never used 'use' declaration before, so it's hard to tell what's wrong. I'm sure it is something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an autoloader or explicitly load the file where that base class is defined?

Comment: Does it work with "use DDelivery\Adapter\PluginFilters;" and "extends PluginFilters"?

Comment: @EdCottrell I'm not sure about it. This snippet above is the beginning of file.

Comment: @Grin well, then, are you calling this file directly, or via an include or require? If you try to use a class name before defining the class, you need an autoloader. If you don't define it and don't have an autoloader, then you will get the error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
use DDelivery\Order\DDeliveryOrder;
use DDelivery\Order\DDeliveryProduct;
use DDelivery\Order\DDStatusProvider;
use DDelivery\Adapter\PluginFilters;


class IntegratorShop extends PluginFilters {
.....
```